# Raphael JS to make a map with tooltips on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, tooltip, raphael

I am trying to make a map with Raphael JS, pretty much like the example they have on their site:
http://raphaeljs.com/australia.html

However, I want to show the info on hover as a tooltip that fades in/out as you move to different parts of the map (not next to the map like on their example). What is the best way to do that?

This is what I came up with so far, but in IE (e.g. IE6 and IE7) the tooltip doesn't disappear and I'm not sure why:
http://jsfiddle.net/keith/sXCk6/

Comment: Same as [How to do a tooltip on an SVG generated by Raphael](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417479/how-to-do-a-tooltip-on-an-svg-generated-by-raphael)

Comment: So I started working on a version, and came up with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/keith/sXCk6/

Can someone tell me if that is the right way to go about this? 

Also, in IE, the tooltip doesn't disappear and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This posting here on Stack Overflow addresses the issue of IE and mouseover problems: [Move active element loses mouseout event in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686132/move-active-element-loses-mouseout-event-in-internet-explorer)