# Tooltip over a Raphael animation - Why won't it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, tooltip, raphael

So I have a piechart drawn with Raphael, I'm trying to create a tooltip that displays Raphael text when I hover over a segment of my pie chart. The event handler hover works fine, but I cant change the coordinates of the tooltip text to match with cursor coordinates. Please see the code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/p7U2K/1/

I've tried

```
posx = e.pageX - $(document).scrollLeft() - $('#holder').offset().left;
```

for my x-coordinate, but it's coming back as undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: still no luck with this piechart? you've got quite a few questions regarding it :)

Comment: Here an example of tooltip over g raphael pie chart... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10991359/617373

Answer (score 2):

I can point out several things you're doing wrong:

- `e` is undefined because you're not passing it to the `.hover` callback
- `$` is also undefined because you're not loading jquery in your script. But you don't need it. You can use `e.offsetX` which gives you relative position to the parent element. You don't need those scroll offsets:

  posx = e.offsetX;
- you are hiding your label instantly after drawing it because of the animate function
- you are creating a new label at each hover event. This will instantly clog your canvas with elements (even if you hide them via `opacity`). Look at this to see what I mean:
  http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/wdzPG/5/

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's been a really enlightening process so far

Comment: Is there a way to destroy the label when hovering out?

Comment: yea, just add a `mouseout` event and call `this.label.remove`

Comment: the click event does not work.the tool tip seems to work fine. what should i do

Comment: @shiba I'm not sure what you mean, you'd better ask a new question

Comment: @mihai inspite of adding this.label.remove at mouseout function the label is not deleted.please help.