# Retrieve attributes of raphael pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, pie-chart

How to get the attributes of raphael pie chart:

attributes like: 
stroke, values (not with legend), radius, x and y position

My pie chart is defined as:

```
pie = r.piechart(120, 140, 50, [55, 22], {
    colors: ["green","red"],
    stroke: "black"   
});
```

I tried:

this.stroke  -- says undefined

// I know this is getting me the raphael object correctly since I am doing some work also

```
this.click(function () { 
   alert(this.stroke); 
});
```

this.attr('stroke'); -- does not even display undefined

Any idea how to solve this...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the pie slice itself like this

```
console.log(this.prev.prev.prev.attrs.stroke); //I know it looks a bit ugly...
```

Or from pie itself like this

```
console.log(pie.series[0].attrs.stroke);
```

Comment: Thanks it works...one more question can we retrieve values also without using legend and without using label

Comment: Actually I have an array of pie chart and I am accessing using $.each(array,function(i,p){ 
         this.click(function(){ 
              alert(this.stroke); 
         });
});

Comment: No it is not working: I did following

 $.each(array, function(i)
    {
        this.click(function () {
            alert(this.series[0].attrs.stroke);
        });
    });